# Why Free Pascal prints 'NO'?

Tags: freepascal

```
var
    a: Integer;  
begin 
    a:= 300;  
    if a in [100..500] then  
        WriteLn ('YES')    
    else  
        WriteLn ('NO')  
end.
```

Comment: It seems that freepascal only allows values <256 for sets, [as can be seen here](http://ideone.com/3ALCc1). No warning seems to be generated by the compiler.

Comment: Oh, yes, maybe. Thank you!

Comment: FPC gives this warning: xxx.pas(1,46) Warning: range check error while evaluating constants (500 must be between 0 and 255)  Do you ignore warnings?

Answer (score 7):

Pascal supports only numbers between 0 and 255 in sets, according to the [FreePascal documentation](http://freepascal.org/docs-html/current/ref/refsu17.html#x41-590003.3.3). The significant portion is here:

> Each of the elements of SetType must be of type TargetType. TargetType can be any ordinal type **with a range between 0 and 255**. A set can contain at most 255 elements.

Turning on range checking `{$R+}` will cause the compiler to warn you of these sorts of errors.